# How to prevent automatically scroll the hidden div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, cordova

For performance, I am not creating many .HTML files. Instead of it I am creating the page content into a div so it will be show like below

```
<div id="page1"> first page content</div>
<div id="page2"> first page content</div>
<div id="page3"> first page content</div>
<div id="page4"> first page content</div>
```

But the problem is, the second page automatically scroll, when I scroll the first page even the second page is hidden.

```html
<button style="position:fixed" onclick="page1.style.display='none';page2.style.display='';">Show page 2</button>
<button style="position:fixed;margin-left:100px" onclick="page1.style.display='';page2.style.display='none';">Show page 1</button>

<div id="page1">
  <div>PAGE 1 -  1</div><div>PAGE 1 -  2</div><div>PAGE 1 -  3</div><div>PAGE 1 -  4</div><div>PAGE 1 -  5</div><div>PAGE 1 -  6</div><div>PAGE 1 -  7</div><div>PAGE 1 -  8</div><div>PAGE 1 -  9</div><div>PAGE 1 -  10</div><div>PAGE 1 -  11</div><div>PAGE 1 -  12</div><div>PAGE 1 -  13</div><div>PAGE 1 -  14</div><div>PAGE 1 -  15</div><div>PAGE 1 -  16</div><div>PAGE 1 -  17</div><div>PAGE 1 -  18</div><div>PAGE 1 -  19</div><div>PAGE 1 -  20</div><div>PAGE 1 -  21</div><div>PAGE 1 -  22</div><div>PAGE 1 -  23</div><div>PAGE 1 -  24</div><div>PAGE 1 -  25</div><div>PAGE 1 -  26</div><div>PAGE 1 -  27</div><div>PAGE 1 -  28</div><div>PAGE 1 -  29</div><div>PAGE 1 -  30</div><div>PAGE 1 -  31</div><div>PAGE 1 -  32</div><div>PAGE 1 -  33</div><div>PAGE 1 -  34</div><div>PAGE 1 -  35</div><div>PAGE 1 -  36</div><div>PAGE 1 -  37</div><div>PAGE 1 -  38</div><div>PAGE 1 -  39</div><div>PAGE 1 -  40</div><div>PAGE 1 -  41</div><div>PAGE 1 -  42</div><div>PAGE 1 -  43</div><div>PAGE 1 -  44</div><div>PAGE 1 -  45</div><div>PAGE 1 -  46</div><div>PAGE 1 -  47</div><div>PAGE 1 -  48</div><div>PAGE 1 -  49</div><div>PAGE 1 -  50</div><div>PAGE 1 -  51</div>
</div>

<div id="page2" style="display:none">
  <div>PAGE 2 -  1</div><div>PAGE 2 -  2</div><div>PAGE 2 -  3</div><div>PAGE 2 -  4</div><div>PAGE 2 -  5</div><div>PAGE 2 -  6</div><div>PAGE 2 -  7</div><div>PAGE 2 -  8</div><div>PAGE 2 -  9</div><div>PAGE 2 -  10</div><div>PAGE 2 -  11</div><div>PAGE 2 -  12</div><div>PAGE 2 -  13</div><div>PAGE 2 -  14</div><div>PAGE 2 -  15</div><div>PAGE 2 -  16</div><div>PAGE 2 -  17</div><div>PAGE 2 -  18</div><div>PAGE 2 -  19</div><div>PAGE 2 -  20</div><div>PAGE 2 -  21</div><div>PAGE 2 -  22</div><div>PAGE 2 -  23</div><div>PAGE 2 -  24</div><div>PAGE 2 -  25</div><div>PAGE 2 -  26</div><div>PAGE 2 -  27</div><div>PAGE 2 -  28</div><div>PAGE 2 -  29</div><div>PAGE 2 -  30</div><div>PAGE 2 -  31</div><div>PAGE 2 -  32</div><div>PAGE 2 -  33</div><div>PAGE 2 -  34</div><div>PAGE 2 -  35</div><div>PAGE 2 -  36</div><div>PAGE 2 -  37</div><div>PAGE 2 -  38</div><div>PAGE 2 -  39</div><div>PAGE 2 -  40</div><div>PAGE 2 -  41</div><div>PAGE 2 -  42</div><div>PAGE 2 -  43</div><div>PAGE 2 -  44</div><div>PAGE 2 -  45</div><div>PAGE 2 -  46</div><div>PAGE 2 -  47</div><div>PAGE 2 -  48</div><div>PAGE 2 -  49</div><div>PAGE 2 -  50</div><div>PAGE 2 -  51</div>
</div>
```

The sample in codepen
https://codepen.io/merbin2012/pen/qBMdVKZ?editors=1000

I know the solution, we can save the final scrolling point and we can scroll when come to the first page and we can use scrolltotop, but it is very difficult to manage, because I have more than 30pages.

Comment: Wait... you have 30+ buttons saying *"Show page N"*? Also, what stops you from using `.scrollTop = 0;` on the scrollable element?

Comment: The mistake you're making here is that you're not actually scrolling a DIV, but the entire document. So your premise is faulty. Use a `.page` instead for all your pages, style it in CSS to have `overflow: auto;` Now all your pages are scrollable independently. What you might want to eventually do is to scrollTop = 0; the active page - if needed.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for your comment, actually, I am using this for my Cordova app. No 30 buttons to show every page, every page buttons are interlinked. I tried to write "overflow:auto", but it is not working, can you please do the changes in codepen link and give?

Comment: Try setting `style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100vw; height:100vh; overflow:auto;"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach using your HTML sample is to address your comment in your original post:

> I know the solution, we can save the final scrolling point and we can scroll when come to the first page and we can use scrolltotop, but it is very difficult to manage, because I have more than 30pages.

A straightforward solution is to: assign a page number attribute to each page element (i.e. your generated HTML content page); add an entry to a `key/value` object; assign the `key` to the page number attribute value; assign `value` to the `scrollTop` position retrieved just before another page element is displayed.

```js
const pageContainerEl = document.documentElement;

const savedScrollTops = {};

document.querySelectorAll("button[data-page-num]")
  .forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", clickHandler));

setActivePage("1");

function clickHandler() {
  // 'this' represents the 'button' element that was clicked.
  // Get the page number in the 'data-page-num' attribute
  // of the clicked button.
  const pageNum = this.getAttribute("data-page-num");

  setActivePage(pageNum);
}

// 'pageNum' parameter can be a integer (e.g. 4) 
// or a string representing an integer value (e.g. "5");
function setActivePage(pageNum) {
  // If the 'pageNum' parameter is set to a string
  // then convert the string to an integer using the
  // built-in 'parseInt()' function.
  pageNum = parseInt(pageNum, 10);

  // If the value assigned to the 'pageNum' parameter is
  // not an integer then exit this function.
  if (!Number.isInteger(pageNum)) {
    return;
  }

  // Get the active page element
  const activePageEl = document.querySelector(".page.active");

  if (activePageEl) {
    // If an active page element exists, get it's
    // 'data-page-num' attribute value and assign it to
    // the variable 'activePageNum'.
    const activePageNum =
      parseInt(activePageEl.getAttribute("data-page-num"), 10);

    // If the requested page number set in the parameter
    // 'pageNum' is the same as the active page number
    // then exit this function as no more code needs to
    // be executed.
    if (activePageNum === pageNum) {
      return;
    }

    if (Number.isInteger(activePageNum)) {
      savedScrollTops[`pageNum${activePageNum}`] =
        pageContainerEl.scrollTop;
    }

    // Hide the active page element by removing the
    // 'active' class name.
    activePageEl.classList.remove("active");
  }

  // Find the page element that has a 'data-page-num'
  // attribute value equal to the value assigned to the
  // 'pageNum' parameter.
  const pageEl = document.querySelector(`.page[data-page-num='${pageNum}']`);
  if (!pageEl) {
    return;
  }

  // Display the page element
  pageEl.classList.add("active");

  // Change the vertical scroll position of the page
  // element to the stored scroll top value in the
  // 'savedScrollTops' object.
  pageContainerEl.scrollTop =
    savedScrollTops[`pageNum${pageNum}`] || 0;
}
```

```css
html {
  /* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior */
  scroll-behavior: unset !important;
}

#button-controls {
  position: fixed;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  width: fit-content;
}

.page {
  display: none;
}

.page.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span id="button-controls">
    <button data-page-num="1">Show page 1</button>
    <button data-page-num="2">Show page 2</button>
</span>

<div id="page1" class="page" data-page-num="1">
  <div>PAGE 1 - 1</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 2</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 3</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 4</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 5</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 6</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 7</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 8</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 9</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 10</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 11</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 12</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 13</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 14</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 15</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 16</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 17</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 18</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 19</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 20</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 21</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 22</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 23</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 24</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 25</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 26</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 27</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 28</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 29</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 30</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 31</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 32</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 33</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 34</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 35</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 36</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 37</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 38</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 39</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 40</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 41</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 42</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 43</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - 44</div>
  <div>PAGE 1 - Slighly shorter content than page 2</div>
</div>

<div id="page2" class="page" data-page-num="2">
  <div>PAGE 2 - 1</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 2</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 3</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 4</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 5</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 6</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 7</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 8</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 9</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 10</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 11</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 12</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 13</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 14</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 15</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 16</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 17</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 18</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 19</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 20</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 21</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 22</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 23</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 24</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 25</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 26</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 27</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 28</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 29</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 30</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 31</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 32</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 33</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 34</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 35</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 36</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 37</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 38</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 39</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 40</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 41</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 42</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 43</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 44</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 45</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 46</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 47</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 48</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 49</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 50</div>
  <div>PAGE 2 - 51</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

- Create a main pages wrapper that flexes `1` (occupy available space)
- Make your pages overlap each-other using position absolute and set `overflow: auto`
- When a page becomes class `"is-active"` set its `scrollTop` to `0`

  ```js
  // DOM utility functions:

  const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
  const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
  const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);


  // Task: Pages 

  const elToPage = el("#toPage");
  const elPages = el("#pages");

  const createPage = (page, i) => {
    const elPage = elNew("article", {
      className: "page",
      innerHTML: `<p><i>Page: ${i+1}</i></p>
                  <h2>${page.title}</h2>
                  <div>${page.body}</div>`
    });
    const elOption = elNew("option", {
      textContent: i+1,
      value: i,
    });
    
    elToPage.append(elOption);
    elPages.append(elPage);
  };

  const showPage = (index) => {
    elPages.querySelector(".page.is-active")?.classList.remove("is-active"); 
    elPages.children[index].scrollTop = 0;
    elPages.children[index].classList.add("is-active");
  };

  elToPage.addEventListener("input", (evt) => {
    showPage(+elToPage.value);
  });
    
  // Grab content and show first page
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(createPage);
      showPage(0);
  });
  ```

  ```css
  * { box-sizing: border-box; }

  body {
    margin: 0; 
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  #nav {
    background: gold;
    padding: 1rem;
  }

  #pages {
    position: relative;
    background: #ddd;
    flex: 1;
  }

  .page {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, scale 0.3s;
    scale: 0.7;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-size: 12vmin;
  }

  .page.is-active {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    scale: 1;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <nav id="nav">Page:
    <select id="toPage"></select>
  </nav>
  <main id="pages"></main>
  ```

Comment: Can you please make changes to the following code? The above one is very difficult and does not solve my problem, because if I scroll the page 1 and go to page 2, that page 2 show should from first line, then if I press the back button, page 1 is should show from where we left.

Comment: @MerbinJoe if that's the case, remove the line `elPages.children[index].scrollTop = 0;`

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand the code.